# Javascript setInterval doesn't work with this. objects

Tags: javascript, class, this, setinterval, move

I'm having a problem with the setInterval() Method in Javascript. My main class:

```
var sq1 = new Square(20, 20);
window.onkeydown = function (e)
{
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (key == 38)
    {
        sq1.moveUp();
    }
}
```

And I have following constructor function.

```
function Square(x,y)
{
    var multiplicator = 10;

    this.xPos = x;
    this.yPos = y;

    this.domObj = document.createElement("div");
    this.domObj.style.position = "absolute";
    this.domObj.style.left = this.xPos * multiplicator + 'px';
    this.domObj.style.top = this.yPos * multiplicator + 'px';
    this.domObj.style.width = multiplicator + 'px';
    this.domObj.style.height = multiplicator + 'px';
    this.domObj.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("idCanvas").appendChild(this.domObj);

    this.moveUp = function ()
    {
        this.yPos--;
        this.domObj.style.top = (this.yPos * multiplicator) + 'px';
    }
}
```

Well that works fine by now, just moving every keyUp event 10px up.
But I would like to call this.moveUp() every 1000 miliseconds automatically after the keyUp event.
But when I try this:

```
this.moveUp = function ()
{
    setInterval(function ()
    {
        this.yPos--;
        this.domObj.style.top = (this.yPos * multiplicator) + 'px';
    }, 1000);
}
```

I get an error that 'this' is null.

How can I fix it (Preferably without jQuery)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the setInterval to the same target as your class.

```
this.moveUp = function ()
{
    setInterval(function ()
    {
        this.yPos--;
        this.domObj.style.top = (this.yPos * multiplicator) + 'px';
    }.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Comment: Down vote huh?  Thought I did that right but maybe not?

Comment: not `scope` but `target`. Also, no classes are involved.

Comment: Yes I know no classes are involved but I though for clarity I'd use the same terms the OP was using.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you need the second to last line to be `}.bind(this), 1000);` for this to work.

Comment: ah shoot you're right.  thx.  Sushanth's answer is much more concise anyway but I'll edit.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The target is the Window object inside `setInterval`

You either need to capture the lexical scope and use it or use `bind` to hard bind the object reference to the handler inside the `setInterval` scope.

**Usage of Lexical scope**

```
this.moveUp = function() {
  // capturing the lexical scope
  var self = this;
  setInterval(function() {
    self.yPos--;
    self.domObj.style.top = (self.yPos * multiplicator) + 'px';
  }, 1000);
}
```

**Using bind**

```
this.moveUp = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    this.yPos--;
    this.domObj.style.top = (this.yPos * multiplicator) + 'px';
  }.bind(this) , 1000);
}
```

Comment: You have a gold badge in JavaScript; certainly you know that this is a duplicate of many questions?

Comment: Assuming you don't need IE 8 and below support, is there any reason *not* to use `.bind()` in this instance?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Most of the solutions are pretty generic as a whole and it requires to grasp the entire content before understanding it. Thought giving out a minimalistic example would help out the OP as he is new to JS.

Comment: @JosephMarikle  `.bind` is the way to go as you can embrace the true intent of using `this` context and understanding it instead of resorting to using `lexical scope` which tries to avoid it.